# CocoaPods - Unable to find a specification for `MobileCenter`

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

Unable to add MobileCenter with CocoaPods. CocoaPods unable to find a specification for MobileCenter.

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'VisualStudioMobileCenterDemo' do
    pod 'MobileCenter'
end
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: It seems that you've already known the answer when you posting this question. Do you need any help?

Comment: @Hoa No, documenting http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
also created the tag `mobile-center` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using Cocoapods to install Mobile Center in your app and run into an error with the message - Unable to find a specification for MobileCenter, run

```
$ pod repo update
```

in your terminal. It will sync the latest podspec files for you. Then try

```
$ pod install
```

which should install Mobile Center modules in your app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your suggested Podfile helps with the problem of the local pod repository not being up-to-date? How is this relevant to the original question?

Comment: @LukasSpieß Updated!! My BaD. I'm thinking something different :(.